# How can I check the number of the item that was clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Let's say I have many items with click event (all have same element name and possibly same class).

```
<a>A</a>
<a>B</a>
<a>C</a>
<a>D</a>
```

then I have method that is triggered on click event. How can I check number of the item that was clicked?

In the example if 'C' was clicked then I should get 3 as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.prevAll()`:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    alert($(this).prevAll('a').length + 1);
});
```

Or `.index()`:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    alert($(this).index() + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
$("a").bind("click",function(){
    alert($(this).index());             // 0 indicates first item
});
```